# What is the purpose of the lambda function in this function and what is the advantage of using it?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

I have this interesting piece of code:

```
def get_unit_sigmoid_func(alpha: float) -> Callable[[float], float]:
    return lambda x, alpha=alpha: 1. / (1 + (1 / np.where(x == 0, 0.01, x) - 1) ** alpha)
```

I just don't understand what the point of this is. Why wouldn't they write something like:

```
def get_unit_sigmoid_func(alpha,x):
    return 1 / (1+(1/np.where(x==0,0.01,x)-1)**alpha)
```

Is there any advantage to the way it's written in the first way?

Comment: You can squeeze the number of lines for functions that don't have a lot to do and its a core concept in Functional programming when using functions as arguments of other functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying). Note: Examples on that question are written in JavaScript but please don't dismiss them - the concept applies equally to any language that supports a functional style of programming.

Answer (score 3):

The function

```
def get_unit_sigmoid_func(alpha: float) -> Callable[[float], float]:
    return lambda x, alpha=alpha: 1. / (1 + (1 / np.where(x == 0, 0.01, x) - 1) ** alpha)
```

returns *a function* that accepts a float value and an alpha. This function sets a default `alpha` value, so you don't need to specify it. This is useful when you need a function with a specific signature (e.g., takes one argument), but there are some parameters you want to set first (like `alpha`).

The function

```py
def get_unit_sigmoid_func(alpha,x):
    return 1 / (1+(1/np.where(x==0,0.01,x)-1)**alpha)
```

returns the value, but notice that it takes an `alpha` parameter and a float.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thank you. Any good resources that further elaborate on these concepts? This is the first time I've seen such detailed type hinting in Python before.

Comment: The first function creates a function that has the __default__ value for `alpha` set, it still allows users to override that.

Comment: This is an example of a "partial function application." That search term should help you find lots of resources on the topic. There is support for this here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial